# Is there documentation of what is needed to port from V1 to V3 of the Eventbrite API?

Tags: api, eventbrite

More specifically, what are the relationships between the various Eventbrite API V1 calls and Eventbrite API V3 calls?  For example, [event_get](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_get/) in V1 is equivalent to [events](http://developer.eventbrite.com/docs/event-details/) in V3.

Comment: please edit your title and question so people know what API you're referencing

Comment: I have made the requested edits. Initially, I was leaning on the Eventbrite tag on the question and I neglected to reference it in the actual wording.